# Can anyone tell me where these "Actions" come from?

Tags: animation, actions

I'm working on a project that features an animated character. I've got a whole humanoid rig / armature that controls all of this.

Sometimes, I'll decide to make changes and add some new objects. It seems like whenever I add these objects (or even transform them in any way), about half the time, they generate themselves these new Actions automatically. Even if I go into the object hierarchy and try hitting `Delete` or `Unlink Action` (no idea what is actually going on under the hood with either of these) - eventually I'll just wind up with more of these empty junk actions that only correspond to that specific object.

You can see below that, for instance, CameraAction was added automatically when I was setting up some renders recently (all of that stuff ending in -Action just magically appeared today while I was working).

Maybe I am just misunderstanding Blender / Actions in principle (to be honest I find the entire animation stack really confusing and I'm just lucky if I remember to create a "fake user" for something I actually do want to keep??) so any insight on this issue is appreciated.

[image: a series of actions in the blender UI]

Comment: In the Timeline, do you have the Auto Keying button enabled (little sphere on the header menu bar)? In that case it will automatically create keyframes if you select and move an object, so disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert a keyframe, it will create a action Data-Blocks in that object.
When you delete that object, the action still in the computer's memory and will not be deleted. When you save the file and re-open the file, these unused Data-Blocks will gone.

This is the same as the material, when you delete the object, the material still here until you quit, make it "fake user" and it will remain.

You also can clean up the unused Data-Blocks manually

[image]

Comment: Is this as a result of having auto keyframing enabled or something? I haven't been trying to insert keyframes. I also thought it was only possible to create keyframes in Pose mode.

Comment: If you copy an object that already has an action, the new object will create a new action.

Comment: All of these objects are brand new, created with the